# Why does my SqlCacheDependency HasChanged come back  false but  almost immediately after changes to true?

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, asp.net-3.5, sqlcachedependency

I cannot figure out why the `HasChanged` value of my `SqlCacheDependency` object is coming back originally from the command execution as false, but somewhere almost immediately after it comes back from the  database, the value changes to true.

Sometimes this happens before the item is even inserted into the cache, causing the cache to discard it immediately, sometimes it's after the insert, and I can grab an enumerator which sees the key in the cache but before I even loop to that item in the cache it's been deleted.

SPROC:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[ntz_dal_ER_X_Note_SelectAllWER_ID]
        @ER_ID int
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT
        ER_X_Note_ID,
        ER_ID,
        Note_ID
    FROM dbo.ER_X_Note e
    WHERE
        ER_ID = @ER_ID
END
```

The database is MS SQL Server 2008, broker service is enabled, and SOME output does cache and remain cached. For instance, this one works just fine:

```
ALTER PROC [dbo].[ntz_dal_GetCacheControllerByEntityName] (
    @Name varchar(50)
) AS
BEGIN
    SELECT 
        CacheController_ID,
        EntityName,
        CacheEnabled,
        Expiration
    From dbo.CacheController cc
    WHERE   EntityName = @Name
END
```

The code which calls the SPROC in question that fails:

```
    DataSet toReturn;
    Hashtable paramHash = new Hashtable();
    paramHash.Add("ER_ID", _eR_ID.IsNull ? null : _eR_ID.Value.ToString());
    string cacheName = BuildCacheString("ntz_dal_ER_X_Note_SelectAllWER_ID", paramHash);
    toReturn = (DataSet)GetFromCache(cacheName);
    if (toReturn == null)
    {

        // Set up parameters (1 input and 0 output)
        SqlParameter[] arParms = {
                new SqlParameter("@ER_ID", _eR_ID),
            };
        SqlCacheDependency scd;

        // Execute query.
        toReturn = _dbTransaction != null 
            ? _dbConnection.ExecuteDataset(_dbTransaction, "dbo.[ntz_dal_ER_X_Note_SelectAllWER_ID]", out scd, arParms) 
            : _dbConnection.ExecuteDataset("dbo.[ntz_dal_ER_X_Note_SelectAllWER_ID]", out scd, arParms);

        AddToCache(cacheName, toReturn, scd);
    }

    return toReturn;
```

Code that works

```
        const string sprocName = "ntz_dal_GetCacheControllerByEntityName";
        string cacheControlPrefix = "CacheController_" + CachePrefix;
        CacheControl controller = (CacheControl)_cache[cacheControlPrefix];
        if (controller == null)
        {
            try
            {
                SqlParameter[] arParms = {
                                             new SqlParameter("@Name", CachePrefix),
                                         };
                SqlCacheDependency sqlCacheDependency;

                // Execute query.
                DataSet result = _dbTransaction != null
                                     ? _dbConnection.ExecuteDataset(_dbTransaction, sprocName, out sqlCacheDependency, arParms)
                                     : _dbConnection.ExecuteDataset(sprocName, out sqlCacheDependency, arParms);

                controller = result.Tables[0].Rows.Count == 0
                                 ? new CacheControl(false)
                                 : new CacheControl(result.Tables[0].Rows[0]);

                _cache.Insert(cacheControlPrefix, controller, sqlCacheDependency);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                // if sproc retreival fails cache the result of false so we don't keep trying
                // this is the only case where it can be added with no expiration date
                controller = new CacheControl(false);

                // direct cache insert, no dependency, no expiration, never try again for this entity
                if (HttpContext.Current != null && UseCaching && _cache != null) _cache.Insert(cacheControlPrefix, controller);
            }
        }
        return controller;
```

The `AddToCache` method is overloaded and has more tests in it; The direct `_cache.Insert` in the working method is to bypass those other tests. The working code helps determine if db caching should happen at all.

You can see that when the "non working" data is retrieved initially, all is OK:

[image]

But somewhere random beyond that point, in this instance, just stepping into the next method

[image]

And yet the data is NOT changing at all; I'm the only one touching this instance of the database.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It was really, really simple, so simple I completely overlooked it.

In this article [Creating a Query for Notification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181122%28SQL.90%29.aspx), which I *DID* scour multiple times, it clearly states:

> SET Option Settings
>
> When a SELECT statement is executed under a notification request, the
> connection that submits the request must have the options for the
> connection set as follows:
>
> ```
> ANSI_NULLS ON
> ANSI_PADDING ON
> ANSI_WARNINGS ON
> CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL ON
> QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
> NUMERIC_ROUNDABORT OFF
> ARITHABORT ON
> ```

Well, I read and re-read and RE-re-read the sproc, and I still didn't see that both ANSI_NULLS and QUOTED_IDENTIFIER were "OFF", not ON.

My dataset is now caching and retaining the data properly without false indicators of change.

Answer (score 1):

I have a hunch that the issue is with your `_eR_ID`. I think that you should try adding a local variable to the failing procedure that uses an impossible value for _eR_ID, such as -1. I never trust what is going to happen when nulls are involved and I think this could be the source of your problem.

Here is the modified version that I recommend trying:

```
DataSet toReturn;
Hashtable paramHash = new Hashtable();

int local_er_ID = eR_ID.IsNull ? -1 : _eR_ID.Value;
paramHash.Add("ER_ID", local_eR_ID.ToString());

string cacheName = BuildCacheString("ntz_dal_ER_X_Note_SelectAllWER_ID", paramHash);
toReturn = (DataSet)GetFromCache(cacheName);
if (toReturn == null)
{

    // Set up parameters (1 input and 0 output)
    SqlParameter[] arParms = {
            new SqlParameter("@ER_ID", local_eR_ID),
        };
    SqlCacheDependency scd;

    // Execute query.
    toReturn = _dbTransaction != null 
        ? _dbConnection.ExecuteDataset(_dbTransaction, "dbo.[ntz_dal_ER_X_Note_SelectAllWER_ID]", out scd, arParms) 
        : _dbConnection.ExecuteDataset("dbo.[ntz_dal_ER_X_Note_SelectAllWER_ID]", out scd, arParms);

    AddToCache(cacheName, toReturn, scd);
}

return toReturn;
```

**Important**

While creating the above code, I think I discovered the source of your problem: when setting the stored proc parameter, you are using `_eR_ID` but when you set the paramHash you are using `_eR_ID.Value`.

The code rewrite will solve this problem, but I suspect that this is the root of the problem.

Comment: I'll try it, but I think it's unlikely, because the param hash is only used to build the key name under which the cache item is created.

Comment: @TheEvilGreebo: Sorry, I don't think I communicated that well enough. I think the problem is this line of code `new SqlParameter("@ER_ID", _eR_ID)`. This passes the entire _eR_ID object to the parameter and I am not sure exactly how it translates that to a value for Sql (I suspect it calls ToString() on the object). Earlier in the code you use _eR_ID.Value, so I think that the minimal change that you need is `new SqlParameter("@ER_ID", _eR_ID.Value)`.

Comment: Oh, I see what you mean.  Well _eR_ID is a SqlInt32 - so one would think that initializing a new SqlParm using that wouldn't cause an issue, but its worth a try!

Comment: Thanks for the try - but it turns out it was something much simpler.  I just needed to look at it again with fresh eyes.

Answer (score 0):

Running into the same issue and finding the same answers online without any help, I was reasearching the xml invalid subscription response from profiler.

I found an example on msdn support site that had a slightly different order of code. When I tried it I realized the problem - Don't open your connection object until after you've created the command object and the cache dependency object. Here is the order you must follow and all will be good:

1. Be sure to enable notifications (SqlCahceDependencyAdmin) and run SqlDependency.Start first
2. Create the connection object
3. Create the command object and assign command text, type, and connection object (any combination of constructors, setting properties, or using CreateCommand).
4. Create the sql cache dependency object
5. Open the connection object
6. Execute the query
7. Add item to cache using dependency.

If you follow this order, and follow all other requirements on your select statement, don't have any permissions issues, this will work!

I believe the issue has to do with how the .NET framework manages the connection, specifically what settings are set. I tried overriding this in my sql command test but it never worked. This is only a guess - what I do know is changing the order immediately solved the issue.

I was able to piece it together from the following to msdn posts.

This post was one of the more common causes of the invalid subscription, and shows how the .Net client sets the properties that are in contrast to what notification requires.

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/cf3853f3-0ea1-41b9-987e-9922e5766066/changing-default-set-options-forced-by-net?forum=adodotnetdataproviders

Then this post was from a user who, like me, had reduced his code to the simplest format. My original code pattern was similar to his.

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/5a29d49b-8c2c-4fe8-b8de-d632a3f60f68/subscriptions-always-invalid-usual-suspects-checked-no-joy?forum=sqlservicebroker

Then I found this post, also a very simple reduction of the problem, only his was a simple issue - needing 2 part name for tables. In his case the suggestion resolved the issue. After looking at his code I noticed the main difference was waiting to open the connection object until AFTER the command object AND the dependency object were created. My only assumption is under the hood (I have not yet started reflector to check so only an assumption) the Connection object is opened differently, or order of events and command happen differently, because of this association.

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/bc9ca094-a989-4403-82c6-7f608ed462ce/sql-server-not-creating-subscription-for-simple-select-query-when-using-sqlcachedependency?forum=sqlservicebroker

I hope this helps someone else in a similar issue.

Comment: I don't think this is correct.  The order is important yes but afaik when you open the connection is not.